# jquery get url from div and insert it into span

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the url from `<div class="ms-vb itx">` and replace it into a href within a span below.
Would that be doable in Jquery?
does that make sense?

```
<td height="100%" class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)">
<div eventtype="" perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" field="LinkTitle" id="5" ctxname="ctx6" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" class="ms-vb itx">
<a target="_self" onclick="EditLink2(this,6);return false;" href="/_layouts/RF.Portal.Web/DetailActualite.aspx?4&amp;ListId={5B770E71-5269-4F45-87A0-2DEFA1136E40}&amp;ID=5&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100FBEA8B5F8E1448F4B48C33A18522E2DA01001677EA3C9B9802408D15440E3B1906DE" onfocus="OnLink(this)">icitait l'honneur d'être reçu,</a>
<img class="ms-newgif" title="Nouveau" alt="Nouveau" src="/_layouts/1036/images/new.gif">
</div>
<div onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;" class="s4-ctx" style="top: 52px; left: 1015px; height: 105px; line-height: 105px; margin: 0px;">
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<a title="Menu Ouvrir" href="javascript:;" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;">
<img style="visibility: hidden;" src="/_layouts/images/ecbarw.png" alt="Menu Ouvrir"></a>
<span>&nbsp;
</span>
</div>
<span style="color: rgb(128, 128, 128);"><em>
          Publié le 07/03/2011 11:30 -
          En cours</em></span><br> et ayant nom Athos, Porthos et Aramis.   Nous l'avouons, ces trois noms étrange<br><br>
          <span style="font-size: 0.9em; color: rgb(128, 128, 128);" id="lireArticle">
          <a class="rfr-link-action" href="DispForm.aspx?ID=5">Lire l'article</a>
        <br><br></span>
        </td>
```

Comment: How do you identify the div you want to take the URL from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just have to make sure that you select the right elements.

E.g.:

```
var $div = $('div.ms-vb.itx');
$div.next('span').find('a').attr('href', $div.find('a').attr('href'));
```

If you have more elements with these classes and you want to perform this for every of them, you can use `each()`:

```
$('div.ms-vb.itx').each(function() {
    $(this).next('span').find('a').attr('href', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

**Update:**

Ok, I assume you have several of these `div`s inside your table and you want to do this for all of them.

The `a` element you want to change seems to have a class `rfr-link-action`, so you can make use of this. Note, although your `span` element has an ID, IDs have to be unique in the document. No two elements can have the same ID.

```
$('div.ms-vb.itx').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('td') // gets a reference to the table cell
    .find('a.rfr-link-action') // finds the link
    .attr('href', $(this).find('a').attr('href')); // sets the URL
});
```

Comment: @user472285: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/z8ZVU/ Maybe your markup is different, then it won't work of course. Or you have an error somewhere else. Can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: @user472285: Now there is no `<span>` element anymore that contains a link. Which `href` do you want to replace?

Comment: oups sorry here again i updated the code with the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
url = $('.ms-vb a').attr('href');
$('#your_span_id a').attr('href', url);
```

But you should have a way to identify your `div` and `span`, e.g. add `id` attributes or smth.

Comment: cool that seems to work :) how would that make that to apply to all the div on the page? like a .eachfunction?